# hive join select very slow

Tags: sql, hadoop, hive, hiveql

hi，i have Two tables: user_info, ip_location, one is 50,000 and the other is 100,000.
now Need to use the ip of the user table to check the attribution，Convert ip to int and compare interval with ip_location。

my hive version is 3.0.0，this version no index。

ip_location：
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jSAEb.png)

This operation is very fast in pg:

```
set search_path=res;
select * from(
select ip,
(split_part(ip,'.',1)::bigint*256*256*256
+split_part(ip,'.',2)::bigint*256*256
+split_part(ip,'.',3)::bigint*256
+split_part(ip,'.',4)::bigint)::int8 as ipvalue
from user_info) t1
left join ip_location t2 on 
ipv4_val_begin=(select max(ipv4_val_begin) from ip_location where ipv4_val_begin <= ipvalue);
```

But I did not find an alternative to this syntax on hive:

```
select ip,
t2.location_country
cast(split(ip,"\\.")[0] as bigint)*256*256*256
+cast(split(ip,"\\.")[0] as bigint)*256*256
+cast(split(ip,"\\.")[0] as bigint)*256
+cast(split(ip,"\\.")[0] as bigint) as ipvalue
from source.v_dm_vip_user t1
left join res.ip_location t2 on 
ipv4_val_begin=(select max(ipv4_val_begin) from res.ip_location where ipv4_val_begin <= ipvalue);
```

error：
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XbEQI.png)

Change to the following sql, you can query successfully, but it is very slow, it takes 1 day：

```
select ip,
t2.location_country
cast(split(ip,"\\.")[0] as bigint)*256*256*256
+cast(split(ip,"\\.")[0] as bigint)*256*256
+cast(split(ip,"\\.")[0] as bigint)*256
+cast(split(ip,"\\.")[0] as bigint) as ipvalue
from source.v_dm_vip_user t1
left join res.ip_location t2 on 
cast(split(ip,"\\.")[0] as bigint)*256*256*256
+cast(split(ip,"\\.")[0] as bigint)*256*256
+cast(split(ip,"\\.")[0] as bigint)*256
+cast(split(ip,"\\.")[0] as bigint) > ipv4_val_begin
and 
cast(split(ip,"\\.")[0] as bigint)*256*256*256
+cast(split(ip,"\\.")[0] as bigint)*256*256
+cast(split(ip,"\\.")[0] as bigint)*256
+cast(split(ip,"\\.")[0] as bigint) < ipv4_val_end;
```

Is there a better and faster sql? I tried a lot but it didn’t work, thanks.

Comment: Does hive version you have support `with` clause ?

Comment: The ```with``` clause can't increase the speed，It still takes about a day，postgres only took 20 sec

Answer (score 0):

I tried the view and row group index, but it can't speed up much. I would like to ask how to use hive to speed up the IP address range like this, and the speed of hive on spark is also slow.